# How can I change the icon for Jupiter?

Tags: 12.04, icons, jupiter

I installed Jupiter to try to improve my laptop's performance, and it's doing rather well :D

However, I use the Radiance theme (white windows, white topbar, black indicator applets etc.) and Jupiter only has a white icon, so I can't really see it... Is there any way for me to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just created 3 icons by inverting the colors. Just extract the files in the archive to:

```
/usr/share/pixmaps/
```

You need Superuser access to do this and [you can download the files here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vjyvr58xf8t39uz/Jupiter_Radiance_theme_icons.tar.gz).

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly - didn't even have to restart Jupiter!

Comment: Had to tweak them a little bit, just to really fit the theme: the icons aren't pure black, they're more grey.

Comment: Not able to download icons... Why?

Comment: Once you click on the download link, a new page opens. You can download the file by clicking on "Download" in the upper right corner.

Answer (score 5):

Jupiter uses icons from `/usr/share/pixmaps/` directory. I've looked through the source code of "Jupiter" and I've found that icon names are hard-coded in application:

```
def update_icon(self):
    m = self.jupiter.get_current_cpu_mode()

    if m == 'high':
        if loaded_indicator:
            self.ind.set_icon('bolt1')
        else:
            self.tray.set_from_icon_name('bolt1')
    elif m == 'powersave':
        if loaded_indicator:
            self.ind.set_icon('bolt4')
        else:
            self.tray.set_from_icon_name('bolt4')
    else:
        if loaded_indicator:
            self.ind.set_icon('bolt2')
        else:
            self.tray.set_from_icon_name('bolt2')
```

So you can replace the following icons with what you like:

```
/usr/share/pixmaps/bolt1.png 
/usr/share/pixmaps/bolt2.png 
/usr/share/pixmaps/bolt3.png  
/usr/share/pixmaps/bolt4.png
```

Surely you can change source code of "jupiter" :)

Answer (score 4):

I've created some new icons [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgmq1coc26b0v84/jupiter-custom-icons.tar.gz) because I didn't like the bold design.